# Django with Postgresql database createsuperuser no response

Tags: django, postgresql

I've tried to use postgresql 10 database with django 2,

when i ran

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

the output indicates the database is doing well.
but when i try to create a supseruser

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

the console actually hangs like below:

```
root@ca80209360d2:/app# python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'root'): tdy
Email address: 
Password: 
Password (again):
```

so after i entered the passwords, it doesn't print out super user created successfully as when I'm using sqlite..

I have to Ctrl+C:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 333, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 261, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 802, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 757, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 130, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 282, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 109, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 150, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 179, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 161, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 144, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 73, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 769, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/app/api/models.py", line 17, in create_auth_token
    task.delay(verification_link, instance.email)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 413, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 536, in apply_async
    **options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 737, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 554, in send_task_message
    **properties
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 494, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 187, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 209, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 38, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 224, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 819, in default_channel
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 405, in ensure_connection
    callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 345, in retry_over_time
    sleep(1.0)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Please help. 
Thank You

Edit:
Below is the docker-compose.yml i used to setup the environment

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  # PostgreSQL database
  db:
    # official postgres:9 with a sql file added to init django database
    image: pg9init  
    hostname: db
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
       - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - pgbackup:/pg_backups

  redis:
    image: redis:3
    hostname: redis

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    hostname: rabbit
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"   # forward this port for debugging
      - "15672:15672" # here can access rabbitmq management plugin

  django:
    # from python:3.5 with all django requirements installed
    image: djangoenvimg  
    command: ./run_django.sh
    environment:
      - DJANGO_ENV=prod
      - DOCKER_CONTAINER=1
    volumes:
      # mount current directory inside container, to avoid the need of re-building the image every time django updates.
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    # instruct all 5 instances of djangoserver containers to share port 8000 via a load-balanced network
    # called backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbit

  # Celery worker
  worker:
    image: djangoenvimg
    command: ./run_celery.sh
    environment:
      - DJANGO_ENV=prod
      - DOCKER_CONTAINER=1
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /home/xx/Android/Sdk:/Sdk:ro
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
      - redis
      - db

# Creates the volume for postgresql database to preserve data during multiple container sessions
volumes:
  pgdata:
  pgbackup:
```

Comment: Is the Postgresql server running?

Comment: Let me guess, you're trying the Postgres version on a different computer than the sqlite version - and on the one with Postgres RabbitMQ is not running or is using different settings?

Comment: @Rafael Yes I think so. In fact even though it hangs, after i Ctrl-C it, the user is indeed created. and i can even use the user to access the admin page.

Comment: @rafalmp everything is set up in a docker-compose.yml file. I do have a separate RabbitMQ service in the same docker-compose, but that RabbitMQ service is for django-celery workers... Do you mean postgres requires RabbitMQ to communicate with Django ???

Comment: I mean the stack trace shows that your user creation process involves sending an account activation link by email using celery, and the ConnectionRefusedError means that Django cannot connect to RabbitMQ.

Comment: @rafalmp oh god.. I see. so it's not the postgres problem, it's the rabbitMQ issue. haha. Thank you ! :)  Will update soon once the bug is fixed.